# Referencing the most recent element in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, element

I'm having trouble with this method "getCurrentReadings()" which is suppose to reference the most recent added element of my ArrayList "meterReadings".

I'm guessing you may use the .get method in the ArrayList class, but how would I reference the most recent element?

Thanks.

```
public MeterReading[] getReadings() {
    MeterReading [] rv = new MeterReading[meterReadings.size()];
    rv = meterReadings.toArray(rv);
    return rv;
}

public MeterReading getCurrentReading() {
    // Need help here
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. And only the relevant part. And what is "most recent"?

Comment: So basically I am storing these meter readings in an array list. The most recent reading is whichever element was last added to the array list. I have a method that returns all of the readings, but I need a method that returns the most recently added reading.

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is correct, your answer is java.util.LinkedList;

```java
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");

System.out.printf(list.getFirst()); // print "a"
System.out.printf(list.getLast()); // print "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the records are added to the List.

If you use:

```
meterReadings.add(new MeterReading());
```

Then get the last record using

```
meterReadings.get(meterReadings.size()-1);
```